# Undo sent application or resend option

Tags: support, jobs

I already applied and sent my resume and realized it is a incorrect one and also cover letter required some edits. Is there a way to revert the application or at least edit the application once sent?

Comment: Is there someone who can help me with this or I should be asking question in some other forum?